# Samsung S4 Health App API's

Tags: android, api, samsung-mobile

I am trying to access to the S Health App Samsung S4 Android app data . Are there public API's available that I can access my own or others data? through an authentication mechanism?

Thanks
Dias L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can signup to become a partner on Samsung at http://developer.samsung.com/account. Once approved you will be sent a app id, app secret and a SDK. Using the SDK you can download Walks, Exercise, Fitness, Food and other body vitals like BP, Glucose etc.